# Character limit on process name?

Tags: chromium, process, conky, system-monitor, top

I notice I can't get much info on processes associated with the chromium browser, whether I am looking at `gnome-system-monitor`, `top`, or the like. Any process associated with `chromium` reads as `chromium-browse`. Obviously it would be helpful to know which tab or sub-process might be responsible for laggy behavior. Is there a character limit on process names, or was `chromium` designed to list processes like this?

Comment: [Could not reproduce.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bvmvd.png)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the built-in chrome's task manager? It can display easily which extension, which app, which tab is using how much memory. 
`Menu -> More Tools -> Task Manager` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping I'd be able to do at-a-glance diagnostics with `conky`, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htop` instead of top. First, install htop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Then, start htop with sudo:

```
sudo htop
```

There are many options. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for a process. Press the <kbd>S</kbd> key to run strace on a selected process.

Comment: Thx. This may be prove useful in the future. For a quick look at memory-hogging tabs, the built-in task manager is what I'm looking for. Any chance you can give me a tl;dr on what to learn from a strace?